# What is the most efficient way to go to Titan?

Tags: propulsion, low-earth-orbit, ion-thruster, chemistry

With ionic motors? or chemical engines? liquid propellant (LH2) or gas? What is the most compact way to make the trip? in the smallest possible rocket, for example the SS-520-5 is a 2-stage rocket, 11.5m high and 50cm in diameter, that can launch loads of up to 1.3kg to LEO, a variant of that to launch 300 / 350kg and we could launch a probe propelled by ionic motors. what do you think?

Comment: What is an "etama"?

Comment: Define “efficient”.

Comment: In other words, do you mean lowest cost, or shortest time, or minimum propellant mass, or...

Comment: The way I have less mass and volume, the time while it is less than 10 years does not matter to me

Comment: SS-520-5 is a three stage orbital rocket. It uses two stage sounding rocket SS-520 and third stage for orbit insertion.

Comment: The literal answer to your question would have to be some kind of photon sailcraft riding a laser beam to launch it toward Titan. The vehicle could be little more than a swatch of metallized film...can't get much smaller or lighter than that. You'll have to constrain the problem more to get a more useful answer than that. Also, note that the smallest and lightest launch vehicles are not necessarily going to be the cheapest...a Falcon 9 that can put 18000+ kg into LEO can go for less than a Pegasus XL that only puts 443 kg up.